# python unicodedecodeerror when operate mysql sentence

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Here is my SQL code:

```
import pymysql
...
conn =pymysql.connect(host="localhost",port=3306,user="username",passwd="password",
                      db="db_name",charset="utf8")
cur  = conn.cursor()


#insert public_figure_info into fb_web_public_figure_info table
public_figure_id = "153080620724"
pf_name = "DonaldTrump"
is_exist_id_sql = "select * from fb_web_public_figure_info where pf_id="+public_figure_id
if cur.execute(is_exist_id_sql) == 0:
    insert_pf_info_sql = """INSERT INTO fb_web_public_figure_info (pf_id,pf_name) 
                            VALUES({0}，'{1}')""".format(public_figure_id,
                                                       pf_name)

    cur.execute(insert_pf_info_sql)

cur.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

It gives this error:

```
<class 'UnicodeDecodeError'> at /public_figure_name_sub
'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 2004: illegal multibyte sequence

Python  C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\web.py-0.40.dev0-py3.6.egg\web\debugerror.py in _get_lines_from_file, line 245
Web POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/public_figure_name_sub
```

Could you please tell me the cause of the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you decoding then encoding? You should have Unicode in your program and then encode for insertion into the database.

Comment: even if no the decoding then encoding, it still errors unicodedecodeerror, could you please correct my program directly

Comment: What is the encoding of the source (.py) file?

Comment: Your code has a syntax error (need triple quotes to close the insert string). Is there any more stack trace than that? I see pymysql code and then an error message about web.py and an http post... are they correlated in some way?

Comment: @tdelaney: Sorry about the triple-quote thing that was a mistake in my edit. It has now been corrected.

Comment: This seems kinda like taking your cat to the vet because your dog is sick. That's a `web.py` error and, cruelly enough, it appears to be an error generated while `web.py` was  trying to read a .py file to get you better information about another error. My guess, and I think its @bernie 's guess also, is that you've deployed a utf-8 encoded .py file onto a machine hosting web.py that as a default encoding of `gdb`. In web.py I see `source = open(filename).readlines()`. I'm not sure how to fix it.